# RxJava how to create Observable from a Subscription

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin

I'm looking for a way to create Observable after processing the result in `subscribe`.

Given I have this Observable from `productRepo.list()` which is **Retrofit** returning `Observable<Response<ProductResponse>>`.

```
productRepo
    .list()
    .retry(3)
    .subscribe { response ->
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            response.body().apply {
                cache.saveProducts(data)
            }
        }
    }
```

The purpose of this is to save the result into local DB `cache`. This plus **another very similar call** populate local DB with remote data from API.

After the two calls completed I wanted to load data from the `cache`.

I don't want to combine both observable in any way. Just want to run some task afterward.

I want this handling as a unit in Rx call graph so that it does Call1 and Call2 at the same time and once Call1 and Call2 completed run Task3. What's the best way in this scenario? I really prefer if the subscriber for each call is separated.

Is `flatMap` the best option here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned,

> I really prefer if the subscriber for each call is separated.

Assume we have two observables

```
val call1 = Observable.from(arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))

val call2 = Observable.from(arrayOf(2,4,6,8))
```

If we purely use `Observable.zip` as following, it only can has **single** subscriber for both two Call1 & Call2.

```
Observable.zip(call1,call2) {c1, c2 -> Pair(c1,c2) }.subscribe(task3Subscriber)
```

If we use three separate subscribers as following, the Call1 & Call2 stream will be triggered **twice**.

```
call1.subscribe(call1Subscriber)

call2.subscribe(call2Subscriber)

Observable.zip(call1,call2) {c1, c2 -> Pair(c1,c2) }.subscribe(task3Subscriber)
```

Therefore, we need to use `.share().cacheWithInitialCapacity(1)` to do the tricks

```
val call1 = Observable.from(arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
  .share()
  .cacheWithInitialCapacity(1)

val call2 = Observable.from(arrayOf(2,4,6,8))
  .share()
  .cacheWithInitialCapacity(1)

val task3Signal = Observable.zip(call1,call2){ c1, c2 ->
  c1 + c2
}
call1.subscribe(call1Subscriber)
call2.subscribe(call2Subscriber)
task3Signal.subscribe(task3Subscriber)
```

You can also prove/test your concept of the Rx graph from a simple Test case.

```
class SimpleJUnitTest {

  @Test
  fun test(){

    val call1 = Observable.from(arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
      .doOnNext { println("call1 doOnNext $it") }
      .share()
      .cacheWithInitialCapacity(1)

    val call2 = Observable.from(arrayOf(2,4,6,8))
      .doOnNext { println("call2 doOnNext $it") }
      .share()
      .cacheWithInitialCapacity(1)

    val task3Signal = Observable.zip(call1,call2){ c1, c2 ->
      println("task3Signal c1:$c1, c2: $c2")
      c1 + c2
    }

    val testSubscriber1 = TestSubscriber<Int>()
    val testSubscriber2 = TestSubscriber<Int>()
    val testSubscriber3 = TestSubscriber<Int>()
    call1.subscribe(testSubscriber1)
    call2.subscribe(testSubscriber2)
    task3Signal.subscribe(testSubscriber3)

    testSubscriber1.assertReceivedOnNext(listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
    testSubscriber2.assertReceivedOnNext(listOf(2,4,6,8))
    testSubscriber3.assertReceivedOnNext(listOf(3,6,9,12))
    testSubscriber1.assertValueCount(8)
    testSubscriber2.assertValueCount(4)
    testSubscriber3.assertValueCount(4)


  }
}
```

Output:

```
call1 doOnNext 1
call1 doOnNext 2
call1 doOnNext 3
call1 doOnNext 4
call1 doOnNext 5
call1 doOnNext 6
call1 doOnNext 7
call1 doOnNext 8
call2 doOnNext 2
call2 doOnNext 4
call2 doOnNext 6
call2 doOnNext 8
task3Signal c1:1, c2: 2
task3Signal c1:2, c2: 4
task3Signal c1:3, c2: 6
task3Signal c1:4, c2: 8
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough example. Appreciated your help. I ended up using `doOnNext` for caching then zip both Observable into one. This make method signature a verbose but it will do.

Answer (score 3):

```
.doOnNext()
```

is your answer, because will return your final response or each response if are multiple. Have a try.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html#collapseRxJava%C2%A02%E2%80%A4x).  Do something like, Observable.zip(firstObservable, secondObservable,.....{Task 3}

Comment: Zip would merge them into a single stream which is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I was wrong about Zip. I ended up using it as well. I mixed up with `merge`. My bad!